# Is there a way to have Ansible replace a block of text with the contents of a file?

Tags: ansible

I am using the replace call in Ansible to replace a block of text. Right now I have the literal value of the text to replace the block with. Is there a way to do something like:

```
  - name: Fixing client_encryption_options in cassandra.yaml
    replace:
      path: '{{tmpBase}}/cassandra.yaml'
      regexp: '(client_encryption_options:[\s\S]*)CBC_SHA]\n^$'
      replace: cat <<someLocalFile>>
```

Comment: On nodes machines or on the controller? This is an important information to [edit] in your question, because the suggestion by the current answer suggest to use a lookup, but this only works on files hosted in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the file [lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html).

```
replace: "{{ lookup('file', 'PATH/TO/LOCAL-FILE') }}"
```

Comment: That worked. Awesome! Thanks!